# JAX-WS web service gets a 400 Bad Request error on client and Broken Pipe error on server for long operations

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I have a Java-based client that receives data from a Tomcat 6.0.24 server webapp via JAX-WS. I recently upgraded the server with new functionality that can take a long time (over 30 seconds) to run for certain inputs.

It turns out that for these long operations, some kind of timeout is occurring. The client gets an HTTP 400 Bad Request error, and shortly afterwards (according to my log timestamps, at least) the server reports a Broken Pipe.

Here's the client's error message:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 400: Bad Request
```

And the server's:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

I've tried experimenting with adding timeout settings on the service's *BindingProvider*, but that doesn't seem to change anything. The default timeout is supposed to be infinite, right?

I don't know if it's relevant, but it might be worth noting that the client is an OSGI bundle running in a Karaf OSGI framework.

Bottom line, I have no idea what's going on here. Note that the new functionality *does* work when it doesn't have to run for too long. Also note that the *size* of the new functionality's response is not any larger than usual - it just takes longer to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was caused by some sort of anti-DoS measure on the server's public gateway. Unfortunately, the IT department refused to fix it, forcing me to switch to polling-based communication. Oh well.